# How can I pass value from one subclass to another subclass in a main class C#?

Tags: c#, class, subclass

I create a class named **MyMainClass**

```
namespace MyTest
{
        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMainClass myVar = new MyMainClass();

            myVar.sub1.sb1A = "value 1A";
            myVar.sub1.sb1B = "value 1B";

            MessageBox.Show(myVar.sub2.wantPassString);
            //I want to print the value "I've got value value 1A"
         }            
    public class MyMainClass
    {
        public subClass1 sub1 = new subClass1();
        public subClass2 sub2 = new subClass2();

        public class subClass1
        {
            public string sb1A{get;set;}
            public string sb1B{get;set;}
        }
        public class subClass2
        {
            public string sb2A{get;set;}
            public string sb2B{get;set;}
            // a1a is a value that I want to get from subClass1
            string a1a = subClass1.sb1A;

            public string wantPassString {get{return "I've got value " + a1a;}}
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass the value from **subClass1.sb1A** to the string **a1a** or **wantPassString** in subClass2 ? when I call in frmMain_Load

Comment: You know that `subClass1` and `subClass2` are not subclasses?

Comment: So what should I called the subClass1 and subClass2 in my app, I thought MyMainClass will cover those 2 so I called it subClass. Otherwise thank you.

Comment: A subclass is when you have `class A { } ` & `class B : A { }` - in this case class `B` is a subclass of `A`. In your case they are just objects and you can call them `X` and `Y` if you want, just not something that is confusing.

Comment: Can you give me some advice to solve my problem to pass the value of myVar.sub1.sb1A into subClass2 without calling myVar.sub2.wantPassString.getvalue(mtVar.sub1.sb1A) by myVar.sub2.wantPassString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach would be to pass the class through the constructor. This works:

```
public class MyMainClass
{
    public MyMainClass()
    {
        sub1 = new subClass1();
        sub2 = new subClass2(sub1);
    }
    public subClass1 sub1;
    public subClass2 sub2;

    public class subClass1
    {
        public string sb1A{get;set;}
        public string sb1B{get;set;}
    }
    public class subClass2
    {
        public subClass2(subClass1 sub1)
        {
            this.sub1 = sub1;
        }
        public string sb2A{get;set;}
        public string sb2B{get;set;}
        subClass1 sub1;

        public string wantPassString {get{return "I've got value " + sub1.sb1A;}}
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your method but when run it pass null to the a1a

Comment: @MonySnap - Yes, sorry. I've changed the code. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a third class to hold the data.

```
public MainClass
{
    private class sharedClass
    {
       internal string sb1A { get; set; }
    }

    public class subClass1
    {

        private readonly sharedClass _shared;
        internal subClass1(sharedClass shared)
        {
            this._shared = shared;
        } 

        public string sb1A
        {
            get
            {
               return this._shared.sb1A;
            }
            set
            {
                this._shared.sb1A = value;
            }

        public string sb1B{get;set;}
    }

    public class subClass2
    {
        private readonly sharedClass _shared;
        public subClass2(shared s) 
        { 
            _shared = s;
        }
        public string sb2A{get;set;}
        public string sb2B{get;set;}


        public string wantPassString {get{return "I've got value " + _shared.sb1;}}
    }

    private readonly sharedClass _shared = new sharedClass();
    private readonly subClass1 _subClass1;
    private readonly subClass2 _subClass2;

    public MainClass() 
    {
        this._subClass1 = new subClass1(this._shared);
        this._subClass2 = new subClass2(this._shared);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank I will try yours.

Comment: Something wrong in the code and I've got error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional property and method and pass it as a parameter:

```
 public string sb2C{ get; set; }
        public string getData(string strParam)
        {
            return sb2C= strParam;
        }
```

Then on your frmMain_Load:

```
MessageBox.Show(myVar.sub2.getData(myVar.sub1.sb1B));
//This would also populate sb2C that will hold the data from the other class
```

Comment: I want the code Done in subClass2 so when I call in frmMain_Load only myVar.sub2.wantPassString i can get value I want.